# Some confusion about $l^p$ space and limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I have problems to understand the notation of sequences of sequences and limits

Let $(x^j)\subset{l^1}$ be a sequences of sequences given by
$x^j_n:=\begin{cases} 0 & n=j \\ \frac{1}{n^2} & \text{else} \end{cases}$

and let be the limit $x_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ then the limit in $l^1$-norm given by
$\sum^\infty_{n=1}|x^j_n-x_n|=\frac{1}{j^2}\rightarrow0$ as $j\rightarrow\infty$.

Is it correct that we compare like this
$|x^j_n-x_n|=(1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\cdots,\frac{1}{n^2},0,\frac{1}{(n+2)^2},\cdots)-(1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\cdots,\frac{1}{n^2},\frac{1}{(n+1)^2},\frac{1}{(n+2)^2},\cdots)$

if so I can not see how the tail of the sum is given by $\frac{1}{j^2}$ and not $\frac{1}{(1+n)^2}$ where $j=n+1$ or can we simply substitute $n=j-1$?

Pleas tell if something is unclear

Comment: Things will become easier if you think of elements if $\ell_1$ (or $\ell_p$ for that matter) as functions on $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ (or  $\mathbb{R}$ if you are working with real numbers). Then, for each $I\in\mathbb{N}$, $x^{I}$ is the function $x^{j}(n)=\frac{1}{n^2}$ if $n=j$ and $x^{j}(n)=0$ otherwise. similarly, your sequence $x:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is  given by $x(n)=\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bit of confusion about the notation it seems. You have
$$
x^j = \left(1, \frac 14, \ldots, \frac1{(j-1)^2}, 0, \frac1{(j+1)^2}, \ldots\right).
$$
Note that the "missing" index is $j$. Note that when we write $x_n^j$ and $x_n$, they are not the whole sequences, but only the $n$'th index. What you have is
$$
x - x^j = \left(1, \frac 14, \ldots \right) - \left(1, \frac 14, \ldots, \frac1{(j-1)^2}, 0, \frac1{(j+1)^2}, \ldots\right)
= \left(0, \ldots, 0, \frac1{j^2}, 0, \ldots\right),
$$
so
$$
|x - x^j| = \frac1{j^2}.
$$
In index notation,
$$
x_n - x_n^j = \begin{cases} \frac1{j^2} & n= j \\ 0 & n\ne j\end{cases},
$$
and then you sum $|x_n - x_n^j|$ over all $n$ to get $\frac1{j^2}$. Remember also, $j$ is fixed here and $n$ is the one we sum over. You can't declare $j=n+1$ or anything like that.

Knowing this, we can now let $j\to\infty$, and we see that $|x - x^j| = \frac1{j^2}\to 0$, proving the convergence. Makes sense?

Comment: So if my understanding is correct is that we take the difference between the $x-x^j$ and then sum over the n-th component of the difference?

Comment: Yes, except before you sum, you take the absolute value of each component. E.g. if $x=(1,-4,3)$, $y=(0,2,2)$, then $|x-y| = |(1,-6,1)| = 1+6+1 = 8$.